# Kafka Console Consumer on Kerberized Cluster : KRBError : Additional pre-authentication required, Server not found in Kerberos database

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api, sasl

Please help me to fix some exceptions while connecting to Kafka broker in a kerberized cluster.

I am running Kafka in version 3.0.0-1 on a Cloudera cluster. Kafka was installed as service from Cloudera Manager (CM). Brokers started fine. I'm able to create and list topics.

But my console producer is not able to connect to Kafka broker topics. I provide  my Kafka client and producer properties below:

**Commands used and errors**

```
[root@local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM ~]$ /opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA/lib/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM:9092 --topic "Kafka-Sucker"  --producer.config /etc/kafka/conf/producer-conf/producer.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-3.0.0-1.3.0.0.p0.40/lib/kafka/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-3.0.0-1.3.0.0.p0.40/lib/kafka/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/03/28 07:38:45 INFO producer.ProducerConfig: ProducerConfig values:
        acks = 1
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.id = console-producer
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = null
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        linger.ms = 1000
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 1500
        retries = 3
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = "kafka"
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name buffer-exhausted-records
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG clients.Metadata: Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)], partitions = [])
Java config name: null
Native config name: /etc/krb5.conf
Loaded from native config
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HADOOP.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): kafka-client
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 93; type: 18
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HADOOP.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): kafka-client
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 77; type: 17
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HADOOP.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): kafka-client
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 77; type: 23
Looking for keys for: kafka-client@HADOOP.COM
Added key: 23version: 1
Added key: 17version: 1
Added key: 18version: 1
>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
Looking for keys for: kafka-client@HADOOP.COM
Added key: 23version: 1
Added key: 17version: 1
Added key: 18version: 1
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23 17 18.
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=ForestAD.HADOOP.COM TCP:88, timeout=3000, number of retries =3, #bytes=180
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=ForestAD.HADOOP.COM TCP:88, timeout=3000,Attempt =1, #bytes=180
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 240 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=240
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = HADOOP.COMkafka-client, s2kparams = null
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 2
         PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 15

>>> KdcAccessibility: remove hadoop.com
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Wed Mar 28 07:37:50 EDT 2018 1522237070000
         suSec is 110488
         error code is 25
         error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
         sname is krbtgt/HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM
         eData provided.
         msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = HADOOP.COMkafka-client, s2kparams = null
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 2
         PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 15

KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23 17 18.
Looking for keys for: kafka-client@HADOOP.COM
Added key: 23version: 1
Added key: 17version: 1
Added key: 18version: 1
Looking for keys for: kafka-client@HADOOP.COM
Added key: 23version: 1
Added key: 17version: 1
Added key: 18version: 1
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23 17 18.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=ForestAD.HADOOP.COM TCP:88, timeout=3000, number of retries =3, #bytes=269
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=ForestAD.HADOOP.COM TCP:88, timeout=3000,Attempt =1, #bytes=269
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1678 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1678
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove hadoop.com
Looking for keys for: kafka-client@HADOOP.COM
Added key: 23version: 1
Added key: 17version: 1
Added key: 18version: 1
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply kafka-client
18/03/28 07:38:45 INFO authenticator.AbstractLogin: Successfully logged in.
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=kafka-client@HADOOP.COM]: It is a Kerberos ticket
18/03/28 07:38:45 INFO kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=kafka-client@HADOOP.COM]: TGT refresh thread started.
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG kerberos.KerberosLogin: Found TGT with client principal 'kafka-client@HADOOP.COM' and server principal 'krbtgt/HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM'.
18/03/28 07:38:45 INFO kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=kafka-client@HADOOP.COM]: TGT valid starting at: Wed Mar 28 07:37:50 EDT 2018
18/03/28 07:38:45 INFO kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=kafka-client@HADOOP.COM]: TGT expires: Wed Mar 28 17:37:50 EDT 2018
18/03/28 07:38:45 INFO kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=kafka-client@HADOOP.COM]: TGT refresh sleeping until: Wed Mar 28 15:42:00 EDT 2018
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name produce-throttle-time
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name connections-closed:
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name connections-created:
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name bytes-sent:
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name bytes-received:
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name select-time:
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name io-time:
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name batch-size
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name compression-rate
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name queue-time
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name request-time
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name records-per-request
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name record-retries
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name errors
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name record-size-max
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name batch-split-rate
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG internals.Sender: Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
18/03/28 07:38:45 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.11.0-kafka-3.0.0
18/03/28 07:38:45 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : unknown
18/03/28 07:38:45 DEBUG producer.KafkaProducer: Kafka producer with client id console-producer created
>Hello World
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Initialize connection to node local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Initiating connection to node local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Creating SaslClient: client=kafka-client@HADOOP.COM;service="kafka";serviceHostname=local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM;mechs=[GSSAPI]
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Added sensor with name node--1.latency
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG network.Selector: Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 102400, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Completed connection to node -1.  Fetching API versions.
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Set SASL client state to INITIAL
Found ticket for kafka-client@HADOOP.COM to go to krbtgt/HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM expiring on Wed Mar 28 17:37:50 EDT 2018
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Found ticket for kafka-client@HADOOP.COM to go to krbtgt/HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM expiring on Wed Mar 28 17:37:50 EDT 2018
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 23 17 18.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=ForestAD.HADOOP.COM TCP:88, timeout=3000, number of retries =3, #bytes=1631
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=ForestAD.HADOOP.COM TCP:88, timeout=3000,Attempt =1, #bytes=1631
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 151 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=151
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove hadoop.com
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 13
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Wed Mar 28 07:37:59 EDT 2018 1522237079000
         suSec is 467340
         error code is 7
         error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
         sname is "kafka"/local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM
         msgType is 30
KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:70)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:251)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(KrbTgsReq.java:262)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:308)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:126)
        at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:458)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:693)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:278)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:278)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:215)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:183)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:76)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:376)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:326)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:454)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:162)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:140)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.init(TGSRep.java:65)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.<init>(TGSRep.java:60)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:55)
        ... 23 more
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG network.Selector: Connection with local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM/10.133.144.108 disconnected
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))]) occurred when evaluating SASL token received from the Kafka Broker. Kafka Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. [Caused by javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))]]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:298)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:215)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:183)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:76)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:376)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:326)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:454)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:162)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:278)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:278)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:770)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:70)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:251)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(KrbTgsReq.java:262)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:308)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:126)
        at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:458)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:693)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:140)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.init(TGSRep.java:65)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.<init>(TGSRep.java:60)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:55)
        ... 23 more
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Node -1 disconnected.
18/03/28 07:38:53 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Initialize connection to node local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Initiating connection to node local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Creating SaslClient: client=kafka-client@HADOOP.COM;service="kafka";serviceHostname=local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM;mechs=[GSSAPI]
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG network.Selector: Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 102400, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Completed connection to node -1.  Fetching API versions.
18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Set SASL client state to INITIAL
^C18/03/28 07:38:54 INFO producer.KafkaProducer: Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG internals.Sender: Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name connections-closed:
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name connections-created:
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name bytes-sent:
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name bytes-received:
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name select-time:
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name io-time:
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG metrics.Metrics: Removed sensor with name node--1.latency
18/03/28 07:38:54 WARN kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=kafka-client@HADOOP.COM]: TGT renewal thread has been interrupted and will exit.
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG internals.Sender: Shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread has completed.
18/03/28 07:38:54 DEBUG producer.KafkaProducer: Kafka producer with client id console-producer has been closed
[root@local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM ~]$
```

**Configurations and environment variables**

```
export KAFKA_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-3.0.0-1.3.0.0.p0.40/lib/kafka
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/conf/producer-conf/kafka-client-jaas.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true"
export JVM_ARGS="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/conf/producer-conf/kafka-client-jaas.conf"
export BROKER_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf"
```

`/etc/kafka/conf/producer-conf/kafka-client-jaas.conf`

```
KafkaServer {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   doNotPrompt=true
   useKeyTab=true
   storeKey=true
   keyTab="/etc/kafka/conf/kafka.keytab"
   principal="kafka/local-dn-1.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM";
};
KafkaClient {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   storeKey=true
   useTicketCache=false
   keyTab="/etc/kafka/conf/producer-conf/kafka-client.keytab"
   principal="kafka-client@HADOOP.COM";
};
Client {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   storeKey=true
   useTicketCache=false
   keyTab="/etc/kafka/conf/kafka.keytab"
   principal="kafka/local-dn-1.hadoop.com.com@HADOOP.COM";
};
```

`producer.properties`

```
bootstrap.servers=local-dn-1.hadoop.com:9092
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.kerberos.service.name="kafka"
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
```

And the command I've used to start the producer:

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list local-dn-1.hadoop.com:9092 --topic "Kafka-Test"  --producer.config /etc/kafka/conf/producer-conf/producer.properties
```

Comment: kafka-client@@HADOOP.COM or kafka-client@HADOOP.COM ?

Comment: It's kafka-client@HADOOP.COM only. typo while de-identifying it. ( was removing aws hostnames ) while posting question on forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided logs I've got as most significant information

```
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Wed Mar 28 07:37:59 EDT 2018 1522237079000
         suSec is 467340
         error code is 7
         error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
         sname is "kafka"/local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM
         msgType is 30
KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)

18/03/28 07:38:53 DEBUG network.Selector: Connection with local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM/10.133.144.108 disconnected
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))]) occurred when evaluating SASL token received from the Kafka Broker. Kafka Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. [Caused by javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))]]
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database Caused by: KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
```

Furthermore `local-dn-1.HADOOP.COM`, as well all other nodes needs to be resolvable (via DNS).

Your `/etc/kafka/conf/producer-conf/kafka-client-jaas.conf` has some entries which seems not to fit together:

```
KafkaServer {
...
   keyTab="/etc/kafka/conf/kafka.keytab"
   principal="kafka/local-dn-1.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM";
};
...
Client {
...
   keyTab="/etc/kafka/conf/kafka.keytab"
   principal="kafka/local-dn-1.hadoop.com.com@HADOOP.COM";
};
```

According this I like to recommend to check the [Configuration of Kerberos Authentication](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/cdh_sg_kerberos_prin_keytab_deploy.html). It seems that Kerberos authentication for node `local-dn-1` is not properly setup yet.

Comment: Here's how I verify Kerberos Config with Kinit from Keytab - 
[root@local producer-conf]# klist -ef
klist: No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1050201141)
[root@local producer-conf]# kinit -kt kafka-client.keytab kafka-client/local.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM
[root@local producer-conf]#
[root@local producer-conf]# klist -ef
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1050201141
Default principal: kafka-client/local.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM

Comment: [root@local producer-conf]# kinit kafka-client/local.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM
Password for kafka-client/local.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM:
[root@local producer-conf]#
[root@local producer-conf]# klist -ef
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1050201141
Default principal: kafka-client/local.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/28/2018 16:56:06  05/29/2018 02:56:06  krbtgt/HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM
        renew until 06/04/2018 16:56:02, Flags: FRIA
        Etype (skey, tkt): arcfour-hmac, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96

Comment: Got it working with only ticketcache as Login with Keytab is not working with console producer which comes with Kafka parcels..[root@local kafka-client-conf]# cat kafka-client-jaas.conf
KafkaClient {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useTicketCache=true;
};

Answer (score 0):

Above error I faced in kafka due to SSL certificates. After fixing the SSL certificates above keerberos error disappeared.

Comment: Could you please provide some details ?